# Enabling TLS/SSL on Postfix

Tags: postfix

I am working on a Postfix server which only sends mails (newsletters).

I have read I should enable TLS and/or SSL on Postfix in order to increase mail deliverability performance. Is it true? Is there a difference between SSL and TLS under Postfix?

I already have these three lines by default on my Postfix installation:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
```

So I am wondering if SSL/TLS is already enabled by default? What are these auto-generated pem and key files? How can I replace them by my HTTPS certificate? I have already an HTTPS certificate for my domain. Can I use the same certificates for both Postfix and Nginx?

Comment: Notice that `smtpd_*` are for configuring incoming mail (server component of Postfix), whereas `smtp_*` are for configuring outgoing mail (client component of Postfix). Your question has configuration for the server, but is actually about the client. My answer is a bit wider than required, as it covers both. I think this way it's more comprehensive for those finding this question in the future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enabling encryption doesn't help with delivery performance, but it's recommendable because it increases **email privacy**. Encrypting email on transport has become a standard, as you may notice from Google's Transparency Report on [Email encryption in transit](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safer-email/overview).

While SSL and older versions of TLS have been deprecated, email is a backwards compatible infrastructure that considers any encryption better than none, and is willing to fallback to unencrypted connections. Therefore, man-in-the-middle attacks would be easy, and techniques like SMTP Security via Opportunistic DANE TLS ([RFC 7672](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7672)) are invented to increase security while maintaining backwards compatibility.

By default (as of May 2020), SSLv2 and SSLv3 have been disabled in Postfix for both

- [`smtp_tls_protocols`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps) – client component for [delivering](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html#delivering) mail &
- [`smtpd_tls_protocols`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_chain_files) – server component for [receiving](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html#receiving) mail.

***My answer summarizes current best-practices & how they could be implemented in Postfix.***

## Inbound TLS

You currently have self-signed default "snake oil" certificates that comes with Postfix.  You told you already have a certificate for your web server and you can certainly use the path for that certificate chain & key, but for this answer to be more useful for the rest, one could also replace them with free Let's Encrypt certificates. For that,

1. use (or install) a web server on the same machine for the [HTTP-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge) and
2. use the certificates created by it for incoming mail.

### Notice that

- your current [`smtpd_use_tls`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_use_tls) is replaced by [`smtpd_tls_security_level`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_security_level) in Postfix ≥ 2.3. Use:

  ```
  smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  ```
- with Postfix ≥ 3.4 the preferred way to configure server keys and certificates is via the [`smtpd_tls_chain_files`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_chain_files) parameter. Pay attention to the correct order: private key before certificate chain:

  ```
  smtpd_tls_chain_files =
      /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem,
      /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem
  ```
- Let's Encrypt has started issuing **ECC certificates** by default [since Certbot 2.0](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ecdsa-certificates-by-default-and-other-upcoming-changes-in-certbot-2-0/177013) which some SMTP servers do not support. In that case, [How to get both ECC & RSA certificates from Let's Encrypt for Postfix?](https://serverfault.com/q/1151325/274176) covers adding an **additional RSA certificate**.
- per [RFC 3207, 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207#section-4) you should use opportunistic TLS on publicly-referenced SMTP servers:

  > A publicly-referenced SMTP server MUST NOT require use of the
  > STARTTLS extension in order to deliver mail locally.  This rule
  > prevents the STARTTLS extension from damaging the interoperability of
  > the Internet's SMTP infrastructure.  A publicly-referenced SMTP
  > server is an SMTP server which runs on port 25 of an Internet host
  > listed in the MX record (or A record if an MX record is not present)
  > for the domain name on the right hand side of an Internet mail
  > address.

Using Let's Encrypt with [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/about/) means your certificates get automatically renewed in 2-3 month cycles. Postfix doesn't load these updated certificates automatically, so it might be wise to reload Postfix (`systemctl reload postfix`) either using Certbot's `--deploy-hook` or regularly with a cronjob.

## Outbound TLS

If you want to add TLS authentication for the receiving servers on your outbound mail, you could use the opportunistic DANE with [`smtp_tls_security_level`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_security_level). Using DANE requires that your DNS resolver has DNSSEC capabilities, and it only authenticates those domains that have TLSA policies published. Again, this is the best-practice for increasing privacy without breaking the backwards compatibility.

> `dane`
>
> - Opportunistic DANE TLS. At this security level, the TLS policy for the
>   destination is obtained via DNSSEC. For TLSA policy to be in effect,
>   the destination domain's containing DNS zone must be signed and the
>   Postfix SMTP client's operating system must be configured to send its
>   DNS queries to a recursive DNS nameserver that is able to validate the
>   signed records.

```
# TLS, DNSSEC and DANE for SMTP client
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
```

If you can't use DANE, you could manually specify a list of domains that you know to have encryption and enforce using TLS for them, alone, using [`smtp_tls_policy_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps):

```
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
```

With this Berkeley DB, the contents of `/etc/postfix/tls_policy` may look like:

```
# Encrypt all mail to @gmail.com using any MX with TLS 1.2
gmail.com encrypt protocols=TLSv1.2

# Ecrypt all mail delivered using a specific nexthop destination
[contoso-com.mail.protection.outlook.com] encrypt
```

## DANE for inbound TLS with Let's Encrypt

For completeness, the outbound DANE verification works best if you also publish your own TLSA records. With Let's Encrypt, it's a bit problematic to automate publishing the fingerprints for your current certificates. Instead, you can use DANE-TA(2) as explained in [Please avoid “3 0 1” and “3 0 2” DANE TLSA records with LE certificates](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/please-avoid-3-0-1-and-3-0-2-dane-tlsa-records-with-le-certificates/7022):

```
_25._tcp.mail.example.com. IN TLSA 2 1 1 (
    60B87575447DCBA2A36B7D11AC09FB24A9DB406FEE12D2CC90180517616E8A18
)
```

Also, for this to work you need a DNSSEC signed zone for your domain.

Comment: can you kindly help with this , hope so, thank you in advance. I'm setting up a development env. I have my windows pc with virtualbox and a virtualized ubuntu server. I'm trying hard to find how to setup encryption on both postfix and dovecot (for dovecot I need IMAPS port 993). My domain is a dummy "develop.box" and I fail with self-signed certificate and so on. Do you kindly have some hint about this?

Answer (score 0):

> enable TLS and/or SSL on postfix in order to increase mail deliverability performance

No. TLS gives encryption for users and during transport but should not effect deliverability unless you are sending to a server that only accepts TLS. What *will* improve deliverabity is properly setting up DKIM, DMARC, MTA-STS records, etc. This is a complex subject not conducive to single answers here.

> difference between SSL and TLS

No difference for your purposes.

> enabled by default

Sending: yes, Receiving: no - a default self-signed cert is installed. There are lots of guides available on the web and `man postfix`. Also [Postfix TLS documentation](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html)

> replace them by my https certificate

Most just drop right in. Again, the web and man are your friends.