# How to get both ECC & RSA certificates from Let's Encrypt for Postfix?

Tags: ssl, postfix, lets-encrypt, certbot

Let's Encrypt has started issuing ECC certificates by default [since Certbot 2.0](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ecdsa-certificates-by-default-and-other-upcoming-changes-in-certbot-2-0/177013). This is not a problem for modern web browsers, but Let's Encrypt certificates can be used for other purposes than HTTPS, too. Namely, some SMTP servers do not support ECC certificates, yet. If such server tries to establish `STARTTLS` connection with Postfix that uses ECC certificates it fails.

The logs indicate there are no shared cipher despite, e.g., Wireshark shows the Client Hello in the TLS handshake clearly has common ciphers with the list configured via `smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium`.

```
postfix/smtpd[1337]: connect from mail.example.net[198.51.100.1]
postfix/smtpd[1337]: SSL_accept error from mail.example.net[198.51.100.1]: -1
postfix/smtpd[1337]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A0000C1:SSL routines::no shared cipher:../ssl/statem/statem_srvr.c:2220:
postfix/smtpd[1337]: lost connection after STARTTLS from mail.example.net[198.51.100.1]
postfix/smtpd[1337]: disconnect from mail.example.net[198.51.100.1] ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 commands=1/2
```

The problem is caused by the type of certificate. Is it possible to get both ECC & RSA certificates from Let's Encrypt using Certbot? How to configure Postfix to use them both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Additional RSA certificate from Let's Encrypt (Certbot)

There are some answers with solutions that require custom scripting. This solution relies entirely on the Certbot configuration. The following assumptions are made. If these differs in your setup, alter the instructions for your needs.

- There is a ECC certificate configured for `mail.example.com` using that as the certificate name (`--cert-name`); renewal configured in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mail.example.com.conf` etc.
- The defaults for Certbot are configured via [configuration file](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#configuration-file) `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini`. This example uses ECC certificates with a stronger `secp384r1` curve (default `secp256r1`) and increased RSA key size `4096` (default `2048`) as well as a pre-configured *authenticator*.

  ```
  # Because we are using logrotate for greater flexibility, disable the
  # internal certbot logrotation.
  max-log-backups = 0

  # Use ECC for the private key
  # (do not set this by default to allow overrides in renewal/*.conf)
  #key-type = ecdsa
  elliptic-curve = secp384r1

  # Use a 4096 bit RSA key instead of 2048
  rsa-key-size = 4096

  # Use webroot authenticator; common webroot for all sites
  authenticator = webroot
  webroot-path = /var/www/letsencrypt
  ```
- **The key is to not set `key-type`, as it will override the one set in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf`.** Hence, the line is commented out.

With this, you can now get two separate certificates:

- ECDSA (only if you did not already have one):

  ```bash
  sudo certbot certonly \
    --cert-name mail.example.com-ecdsa \
    -d mail.example.com \
    --key-type ecdsa
  ```
- RSA:

  ```bash
  sudo certbot certonly \
    --cert-name mail.example.com-rsa \
    -d mail.example.com \
    --key-type rsa
  ```

If your renewal method is configured correctly you should get:

```
Requesting a certificate for mail.example.com

Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-ecdsa/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-ecdsa/privkey.pem
```

&

```
Requesting a certificate for mail.example.com

Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-rsa/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-rsa/privkey.pem
```

You will need these paths in the Postfix configuration.

## Multiple certificates in Postfix

With [Postfix TLS Support](https://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html) you can configure multiple certificates at the same time. Since Postfix 3.4 it has been recommended to use the [`smtpd_tls_chain_files`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_chain_files) parameter (instead of the legacy `smtpd_tls_cert_file` & `smtpd_tls_key_file` for RSA & `smtpd_tls_eccert_file` & `smtpd_tls_eckey_file` for ECDSA).

It is worth to note that:

> You can also store the keys separately from their certificates, again provided each is listed before the corresponding certificate chain. Storing a key and its associated certificate chain in separate files is not recommended, because this is prone to race conditions during key rollover, as there is no way to update multiple files atomically.

However,

- Certbot stores the key and the chain in separate files.
- You can configure a `--deploy-hook` with a script that runs `systemctl reload postfix` on a successful renewal.

Example configuration for the `main.cf`; pay attention to the correct order: each private key before each certificate chain:

```
smtpd_tls_chain_files =
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-ecdsa/privkey.pem,
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-ecdsa/fullchain.pem,
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-rsa/privkey.pem,
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-rsa/fullchain.pem
```