# How do I properly issue Let's Encrypt certificate for my mail server?

Tags: postfix, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, starttls

How do I properly issue Let's Encrypt certificate for my Postfix mail server?
Right now I have a self-signed certificate and I get these messages it cannot be trusted.

I did certbot --nginx certonly -d mail.example.org and apparently it is self-signed.

Comment: Why do you believe it's self signed?

Comment: You did NOTHING to tell Postfix about the certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan is correct - the `--certonly` option tells certbot to get the certificate but do nothing with it. The script will have told you where that certificate is now, most likely `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.org`, as files named `cert.pem`, `chain.pem`, `fullchain.pem`, and `privkey.pem`. You would go into configuration for Postfix, and change the certificate paths to point to those files. Once you've done that, of course, you would restart Postfix.

Comment: I have done that in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

Comment: Dovecot is for talking to your mail clients and handles IMAP and POP. You also have to do it for Postfix which is your mailer and handles SMTP.

Comment: where do I find the relevant config file
?

Comment: `sudo postconf -d` will show you where the config directory is. You're looking for either `main.cf` or `master.cf`. Strong suggestion: `man postfix` and read a lot.

Comment: Found it! Thank you guys a lot!!!

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please mark it as the solution by clicking the check mark beside the answer; that lets others seeing your question know that an answer has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Encrypt, [since Certbot 2.0](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ecdsa-certificates-by-default-and-other-upcoming-changes-in-certbot-2-0/177013), issues ECC certificates by default. Some sending mail systems do not yet support those, but only RSA certificates.Therefore, to *properly issue* certificates for a Postfix mailserver, you would need two sets of certificate+key files:

```
smtpd_tls_chain_files =
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-ecdsa/privkey.pem,
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-ecdsa/fullchain.pem,
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-rsa/privkey.pem,
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com-rsa/fullchain.pem
```

You can get them by commenting out `key-type` in `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini` and then issuing the certificates with the `--key-type` option in command line. That part is crucial, because the settings in `cli.ini` will override those in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf`, which will break things on the next automatic renewal. E.g.,

```bash
sudo certbot certonly \
  --cert-name mail.example.com-ecdsa \
  -d mail.example.com \
  --key-type ecdsa

sudo certbot certonly \
  --cert-name mail.example.com-rsa \
  -d mail.example.com \
  --key-type rsa
```

A more elaborate answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1151326/274176